# The statistical power decreases as the time point change in the data increases

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, quantile-regression

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ the data generated by the signal plus noise model having a change in mean at $\tau\in\Pi=[t_1,1-t_1],\;0<t_1<1$, which defined by:

$$\begin{cases} X_t=\rho_0+\varepsilon_t,\;t=1,\dots,\lfloor n\tau\rfloor\\X_t=\rho_0+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\beta+\varepsilon_t,\;t=\lfloor n\tau\rfloor+1,\dots,n,\end{cases}$$
with $\varepsilon_t$ are i.i.d normal random variables.
The corresponding code in R is given by:

```
g=floor(n*tau) # the integer part of n*tau
E=rnorm(n)
  X=numeric()
  X[1:g]=ro+E[1:g]
  X[(g+1):n]= ro+(beta/sqrt(n))+E[(g+1):n]
```

the test statistic used to detect this change is given by:

$$KS=\sup_{t_1\lt \tau\lt 1-t_1}\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{t=\lfloor n\tau\rfloor+1}^n\left[X_t-\rho_0-\dfrac{\beta}{2\sqrt{n}}\right]\right|.$$

The corresponding code is given by:

```
 LAM=numeric()
 LAM=cumsum((X-ro-beta*0.5)/sqrt(n))
 #Kolmogorov Smirnov theorique
 KS=max(abs(LAM[n1:n2]))
```

His limit distribution is given by:

$$\widetilde{KS}=\sup_{t_1\lt \tau\lt t_2}\left|W(1)-W(\tau)-\dfrac{1-\tau}{2}\beta\right|,$$
$W(.)$ is standard Brownian motion.

The correponding code is given by:

```
 LKS=numeric(1000)
for(l in 1:1000){
  #Simulate brownian motion w(1)-w(tau)
B=rnorm(m)
CUM=cumsum(B)/sqrt(m)
LAMDA=CUM-(1-tau)*0.5*beta
LKS[l]=max(abs(LAMDA[m1:m2]))
}
```

To calculate the power of $KS$, I calculate the quantile of $\widetilde{KS}$ with $\alpha=0.05$ level order

$$q_{\widetilde{KS}}(\alpha)<KS.$$

I repeat this procedure 1000 times and his mean is considered the empiric power of $KS$.
The different power values are shown in the figure below.
[image]

I'm wondering why the empirical power decreases when the value of the $\tau$ time change increases. I also want to know if my code is correct or not.

In the literature, it is observed that power is at its highest in the middle of the change-point interval and lowest at the beginning and end of the interval, as illustrated in the figure below.
[image]

The complete main code is provided below:

```
Test=function(n,nb,alpha,tau,beta){
#Simulate of the observatipon solution of the model shift
ro=0.5
Vtau=(1:n)/n
g=floor(n*tau)
prob=logical(nb)
n1=10
n2=n-n1
m=2000
Vtau1=(1:m)/m
m1=20
m2=m-m1
#################
for( k in 1:nb){
 E=rnorm(n)
 X=numeric()
 X[1:g]=ro+E[1:g]
 X[(g+1):n]= ro+(beta/sqrt(n))+E[(g+1):n]
 Obs=X-ro

LAM=numeric()
LAM=cumsum(Obs)/sqrt(n)-(1-Vtau)*0.5*beta
#Kolmogorov Smirnov theorique
KS=max(abs(LAM[n1:n2]))
 #####################
LKS=numeric(1000)
for(l in 1:1000){
 #Simulate brownian motion w(1)-w(tau)-((1/tau)/2)beta
B=rnorm(m)
CUM=cumsum(B)/sqrt(m)
LAMDA=CUM-(1-Vtau1)*0.5*beta
LKS[l]=max(abs(LAMDA[m1:m2]))
}
quant=quantile(LKS,(1-alpha))
prob[k]=(quant<KS)
 }
mean(prob)
}







Test(100,1000,0.05,0.1,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.2,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.3,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.4,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.5,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.6,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.7,3)
Test(100,1000,0.05,0.7,3)
```

I hope my problem and question have been clearly expressed. I worked on it for several months but didn't understand what the problem was with having that much power.

I am very interested in your comments and ideas.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your code for "KS" does not appear to implement the formula you quote.